# Is Hausdorff outer measure sigma finite when restrict on a set with same dimension

Tags: real-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

For a set $E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff outer measure is defined as $\mathcal H^s(E)=\lim\limits_{\delta\to0}\mathcal H^s_\delta(E)$, where
$\mathcal H^s_\delta(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty (diam F_k)^s:E\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty F_k,diam F_k<\delta\right\}$.

The Hausdorff dimension of $E$ is defined as $\dim E=\inf\{s<n:\mathcal H^s(E)=0\}$

Suppose $E$ is a Borel set (hence is truly Hausdorff measurable) and has dimension $s$. Define a Borel measure $\mu_E$ by $\mu_E(F)=\mathcal H^s(E\cap F)$.

Does $\mu_E$ a sigma-finite measure?

It's obvious that $\mu_E$ is finite if $\mathcal H^s(E)<\infty$, but in general, I don't know how "big" for $E$ can be.

Comment: I think your definition of the Hausdorff dimension is wrong... it should read $\dim_{\mathcal{H}}E = \inf\{0\leq s < +\infty:\mathcal{H}^s(E)=0\} = \sup\{s:\mathcal{H}^s(E)=+\infty\}$.

Comment: @yousufsoliman it won't exceed n

Comment: Sure... but you have a sup when it should be an inf

Comment: @yousufsoliman You're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) are uncountable and are of Hausdorff dimension zero. Since the $\mathcal{H}^0$ is the counting measure, this shows that $\mu_E$ is not $\sigma$-finite where $E$ denotes the set of Liouville numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. You can find a proof of this in Oxtoby's *Measure and Category* (Theorem 2.4).

Comment: A more extreme result for the Liouville numbers is in [*Borel sets which are null or non*-$\sigma$-*finite for every translation invariant measure*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804003846) by Márton Elekes and Tamás Keleti.